# Где хранится история firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox

Мне надо перенести на другой компьютер профили браузеров.
Если я скопирую просто на другой компьютер папки. Смогу ли просматривать историю поиска, текущие открытые вкладки смотреть?

Мне нужно в общем перенести на другой компьютер профиль, и смотреть текущие открытые вкладки. Они у меня сохраняются.

Как мне это сделать?

Firefox: `C:\Users\имя пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`

Comment: задайте, пожалуйста, вопросы про разные браузеры по отдельности. я оставлю в текущем вопросе только упоминания про firefox. вам остаётся задать вопрос про chrome.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы здесь принято задавать по-отдельности. для начала мы вам помогаем привести текст вопроса к существующим требованиям сайта.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin оставьте про хром - вопрос то один и тот же

Comment: @eri, это совершенно разные программы. и хранят свои настройки совершенно по-разному. я считаю, что вопросы никак не связаны.

Comment: Вопрос один и тот же, программы хоть и разные - делают одно и то же, настройки хранят одинаково, только в разных файлах.

Comment: @eri, я вот насчитал [63 бразуера в списке](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers). это лишь распространённые. сотни (а может и тысячи) всякой малоизвестной мелочёвки там отсутствуют. для полноты ответа надо хотя бы про эти 63 написать. это ирония. // вы же сами понимаете: кто-нибудь задаст завтра вопрос про пару opera/firefox, кто-то про пару explorer/chrome и т.п. — что делать с такими вопросами?

Comment: yandex==opera==chrome==и т.д., сафари нет под виндовс, а ie/edge никого не  интересуют. Браузеры меньше 10% не стоят внимания.

Answer (score 3):

## Firefox

Если просто перенести папку вместе с profiles.ini - заработает. Текущие вкладки откроет если в настройках стоит открывать вкладки.

Если запустить Firefox с параметрами   `--new-instance --profile <path>` то можно указать расположение профиля не устанавливая его как основной.

История браузера хранится в `places.sqlite` - можно открыть в [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), например.

## Chrome, Opera, Yandex

Профиль также запустится при перемещении на другой компьютер. Вкладки останутся если в настройках стоит открывать последние вкладки при запуске.

История хранится в файле History - просмотреть его также можно через Sqlite браузер. Только нужно закрыть хром.

Хром можно запустить с профилем в другой папке через параметры `--user-data-dir=DIR`

Comment: в вопросе нет ничего про хром)

Comment: наверно, стоит разнести ответы — про chrome есть [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1121152/178576)

Answer (score 2):

В `firefox` в строке адреса введите `about:profiles`. Выведет расположение папок всех профилей текущего пользователя. Или `about:support` - выведет больше информации.

При переносе папок на другой компьютер, чтобы избежать проблем с совместимостью версий, удалить в них файл `compatibility.ini` (преименовать в `compatibility_old.ini`).

Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: about:profiles]