# Где хранится история Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Мне надо перенести на другой компьютер профиль браузера Chrome. Если я скопирую просто на другой компьютер папку. Смогу ли просматривать историю поиска, текущие открытые вкладки смотреть?

Мне нужно в общем перенести на другой компьютер профиль, и смотреть текущие открытые вкладки. Они у меня сохраняются.

Как правильно поступить?

Chrome: C:\Users\имя пользователя\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: Есть такая штука, как синхронизация. Создаете аккаунт Google, потом войдите в него на другом компьютере, при этом, у вас перенесутся все закладки/история/пароли. Так же, вы сможете отправлять открытые вкладки на другое устройство. https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840875?hl=ru

Comment: мне кажется тут затевается всё для контроля жены/сотрудников или ещё какого-нибудь шпионажа. Врятли тащит свой профиль судя по формулировке вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Где хранится история firefox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121128/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Chrome

Профиль также запустится при перемещении на другой компьютер. Вкладки останутся если в настройках стоит открывать последние вкладки при запуске.

История хранится в файле History - просмотреть его также можно [через Sqlite браузер](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). Только нужно закрыть хром.

Хром можно запустить с профилем в другой папке через параметры `--user-data-dir=DIR`

Comment: спасибо вам сэр

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\имя пользователя\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.